# Hacer un UPDATE en muchos registros, MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada `archivos` en mi bd (uso MySQL), en la cual tengo los siguientes campos: id, nombre, created, uploaded, deleted. El campo `nombre` tiene este formato:

> [fecha]-[remitente]-[destinatario]-[nombre_del_archivo]

No debe haber dos archivos o más con el mismo nombre, en tal caso, se deben marcar como `eliminados` los archivos mas antiguos colocando el valor `deleted = "[fecha_de_hoy]"`, y el más reciente debe tener `deleted = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"`, ejemplo:

```
id|         nombre                  |     created    |     uploaded   |      deleted

1 |20210221-juan-maria-te_quiero.jpg|2020-02-21 18:15|2020-02-21 18:16|0000-00-00 00:00:00
2 |20210221-juan-maria-te_quiero.jpg|2021-01-01 12:08|2021-01-01 12:09|0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 |20210221-maria-juan-te_quiero.jpg|2020-02-21 19:15|2020-02-21 19:16|0000-00-00 00:00:00
4 |20210221-maria-juan-te_quiero.jpg|2021-01-01 13:08|2021-01-01 13:09|0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

debe sustituirse por:

```
id|         nombre                  |     created    |     uploaded   |      deleted
    
1 |20210221-juan-maria-te_quiero.jpg|2020-02-21 18:15|2020-02-21 18:16|2021-02-21 21:21:00
2 |20210221-juan-maria-te_quiero.jpg|2021-01-01 12:08|2021-01-01 12:09|0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 |20210221-maria-juan-te_quiero.jpg|2020-02-21 19:15|2020-02-21 19:16|2021-02-21 21:21:00
4 |20210221-maria-juan-te_quiero.jpg|2021-01-01 13:08|2021-01-01 13:09|0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

La tabla tiene alrededor de 400.000 registros, existen muchos conjuntos de nombres repetidos en donde se tiene que aplicar la regla del ejemplo de arriba.

Hasta ahora se me han ocurrido 2 soluciones:

1. Crear 2 archivos PHP, en uno traer todos los registros y
   almacenarlos en un archivo de texto, y en otro leer ese archivo de
   texto y almacenar los datos en un array para posteriormente marcar
   los duplicados como eliminados, luego guardar el resultado en un
   archivo de texto y por último vaciar la tabla e importar los datos
   que están en el nuevo archivo de texto.
2. Con subconsultas, en primera instancia construí un SELECT para traer aquellos registros que se van a eliminar (los más antiguos) y
   constatar que todo está bien para posteriormente proseguir con un
   UPDATE en lugar del SELECT, hasta ahora esto es lo que llevo (no sé
   si está bien):

`SELECT id, nombre, created, uploaded, deleted FROM archivos a WHERE deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND uploaded <> (SELECT MAX(uploaded) FROM archivos b WHERE b.name = a.name)`

La cuestión es, que al tener una cantidad tan grande de datos, estoy ante dos problemas:

1. Desbordamiento de la memoria (me sucede con PHP).
2. La subconsulta es eterna, nunca veo el resultado (usando phpmyadmin).

Answer (score 0):

Sí solo te interesa tener las líneas con los archivos más nuevos, podrías crear un tabla nueva llamada archivos_nuevo con las mismas columnas que archivo, y realizar una insert con select, con un group by. En el campo deleted de la nueva tabla indicas que por defecto sea '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

```html
INSERT 
  INTO archivos_nuevo (id, nombre, created, uploaded) 
 VALUES 
  SELECT id, nombre, MAX(created), MAX(upload) FROM archivos GROUP BY id,nombre
```